# How to share cookies from two different application?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, tomcat, iis, cookies

I have two application, one in `java (hosted on tomcat/Linux)` and another is in `asp.net mvc (hosted on IIS)`. Right now these two application asks for authentication. They share the same database(**MySQL**), and authentication information is stored in **MySQL**.

The java application is opened from `asp.net mvc` application after authentication to `asp.net mvc` application. The same credentials are used for `java/tomcat` application. When I open the application the java application asks for authentication which I am trying to avoid since it uses the same authentication.

One of the way that I think could be using **cookies** between each other. Can someone help me to understand it this is possible, if yes, how can I do this?

Also appreciate if you can suggest me any other approach to make this possible.

I access these applications as below.

asp.net mvc application : `http://demo.example.com`
java application : `https://demo.example.com/javaapp`

Comment: If they are on the same domain, then they share cookies.

Comment: @vcsjones Thank you for your reply. In my case it asks for authentication. 
`http://demo.example.com` this is on `IIS` where as **/javaapp** is a folder in tomcat7 under **webapps** folder. If this is the case how can I use the same cookies?